How can I understand if a Kotlin project is Gradle-Kotlin or Gradle-Groovy?
actually the title is self explanatory but I'm a beginner in Java and Kotlin environments. I have to rewrite a project from scratch and I don't have much experience with these languages and their environment. How can I understand from looking a project if it's Gradle-Kotlin or Gradle-Groovy based?
The project that I will transfer is written in Maven, I know that. But I want to implement a spesific architecture with same structure of a different project, so I need to understand what is what. Than, I can initialize my project with that DSL of I need.
I looked a Kotlin project as it indicated Gradle some places but I also saw Gradle-Groovy template in it so I'm not totally sure if it is Gradle-Kotlin or Gradle-Groovy.

Find out which language the gradle build script is written it. If it's Kotlin, you will find a build.gradle.kts in your project root, otherwise it's groovy in a build.gradle.

@deHaar thank you for you comment.  It's the first one, and I got the point now. Thanks for the answer!

1. Check the Build Script File Extensions:
Gradle-Kotlin DSL:

build.gradle.kts
settings.gradle.kts
init.gradle.kts 
Gradle-Groovy DSL:
build.gradle
settings.gradle
init.gradle

2. Examine the Syntax in the Build Files:

Gradle-Kotlin DSL:

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.10"
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
}


Gradle-Groovy DSL:

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.5.10'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
}


I marked it as answer, thank you!!
